# Anyway I can improve my answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My answer to "Why do ketoses undergo dehydration more rapidly than aldoses?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/180178/139890)

I have given an answer to the above question and while it seems good, I don't see much upvotes for it, which gives me a doubt as to whether it can be improved. Can anyone please let me know about it?

What I felt was:

1. *It's very long:* But I have summarised the answer for those who don't have the patience to read such a long answer.
2. *It lifts a portion of the research paper as it is:* But I have quoted the paper which I used as my reference for the answer.

---

Another situation for my answer to this question too... I feel it's good, but only 1 upvote is there:

[Inductive effect on stability of free radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/inductive-effect-on-stability-of-free-radical/179556#179556)

Any other points to add on?

Comment: Well, sad thing is votes barely correlate with quality of posts. I think you used unnecessary slant in citations, and there's some weird indentations in a table... otherwise TL:DR ;)

Comment: That's the thing with (long) specialistic answers, people tend to vote less, because it's much more difficult to check.

Comment: Five upvotes is pretty good, particularly on a fairly specialist answer. I’ve got a few answers I think are pretty good with no upvotes. C’est la vie…

Comment: @Mithoron basically I am not a pro in Mathjax / $\LaTeX$ yet, so it would be of great help if anyone can improve the formatting of my answer. But I've tried my best to keep it good-looking, so that the point that I am trying to raise remains clear. My purpose of including a separate summary is to get my answer to those who can't / don't have enough patience to read out the whole answer (ig really big diagrams made it LOOK extremely long)

Comment: Btw I am certainly NOT a specialist in biochem - and I really am not able to see how you think that it is a specialist answer.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM While it would be convenient to you if someone else improved the formatting of your answer, it would be of greater value if you learned how to format your own answers in the manner expected from the community.

Comment: [Here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/99197/17368) is one of my answer written many years ago. At that time, I was new to writing answers and I was proud of the way I constructed and wrote the answer. Sadly, it has only one upvote. As mentioned already, votes barely correlate with quality of posts. Even if you have written a good answer, it is not going to be upvoted if it never reaches the attention.

Comment: @NilayGhosh saw your answer, such a clear, concise, gem of an answer...! But anything and everything depends on how many people actually *see* the answer it seems eod... seems I am lucky enough to get 6 atleast... but are there any strategies to drill our answer down to make it popular?

Comment: You can edit your posts from time to time, bumping them to homepage. If they're good, there's a fair chance for getting a bit more rep. Even without that votes tend to accumulate with time. It's all a long run though - matter of years.

Comment: @Mithoron I feel like deleting your last comment. Frequent bumps not associated with edits resulting in significant improvements should be avoided. Imo what is unfortunate is that some posts get plenty of views but a very small fraction of visitors bother to upvote even if they find a post useful. Stuff for Psych 101. If you want to get a bump in reputation go farm. Increase your number of answers or pick questions likely to become popular.

Comment: @BuckThorn still rep farming is still against the sanctity of the community, imo. I am a 2-month-old member here and managed to get rep because of answers I've managed to write (almost 22 votes = 220 pts + 2 accepted answers (30 pts))= 250 pts, ignoring all my downvotes and rep losses in bounties. And few of them done by rep-farming. Comparatively, the most recent answers I have given saw selected unanswered good questions, and I had more patience while writing answers. Thus they are better formatted, better taken care of.

Comment: Not farming for rep helped me 1) get my answers better, 2) format them more legibly, 3) research more and see in what ways I can express my answer, 4) Make them look as if a specialist wrote that answer. I guess thats the thing

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177842/are-all-bond-lengths-equal-in-8annulene/177845#177845

this question includes my answer before rep farming, and after rep farming

Comment: That comment about rep farming was meant somewhat sarcastically. Perhaps I should not have made it. I linked to a post on rep farming in your other recent meta post on AI. The desire to gain rep is understandable. It's for instance the only way to acquire more onsite privileges. If you are interested in rep etc you may want to look at this: https://learning.mpi-sws.org/networks-seminar/papers/posnett-socinf12.pdf

Comment: In general, you first become knowledgeable, then you share your knowledge. However, sometimes I write answers on subjects in which I can't claim deep expertise, but based on my experience and research I might find an answer anyway which I feel is worthy of being posted.

Comment: see also: https://epjdatascience.springeropen.com/articles/10.1140/epjds/s13688-023-00381-x